# Creating a unique image name hash for a website with image uploads

Tags: filesystems, hash, image-uploading

I have a website that accepts user-uploaded images. I want to give each uploaded image a unique name. I will be physically storing the images on the file system and saving the file-name of the image in my database. What is a good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can name it  a substring  of a md5 hash made of the users id and the time

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason not to use an autogenerated ID field in the table and make that the file name as well.

Comment: I want something that isn't guessable by other users

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that in the question

Comment: For instance if I just hash the table index that might be guessable? MD5 ("1") = c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
MD5 ("2") = c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c